# Ajax request inside ajax request with Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a code that works like this:

```
 $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        dataType: 'html',
```

This loads:

```
Route::post('/local/pdf', 'LocalController@subirPDF');
```

Which loads the controller:

```
return View::make(Config::get('rv.paginasPDF'));
```

Which loads:

```
$.get("{{Request::root()}}/local/actualizar_paginas/9/2");
```

Which loads the route:

```
Route::get('/local/actualizar_paginas/{id}/{paginas}', 'LocalController@actualizarPaginas')->where('id', '[0-9]+')->where('paginas', '[0-9]+');
```

That loads:

```
Auth::user()->perfil='penadaaaaaafe';
Auth::user()->save();
```

Don't worry if you see that I don't use some variables, because I have simplified the code to make it easier to explain.

Basically, if I load directly the route from the url everything works fine:

```
{{Request::root()}}/local/actualizar_paginas/9/2"
```

But if I load it with the ajax method that I have devoloped it doesn't work. If I console.log the data I recieve the right html code of the $.get page, but It doesn't make the get request.

Any idea how to fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know anything about laravel, but if I understand that right you have JS-Code inside the AJAX-Response? This JS-Code will not lunch automaticlly, you have to call it.

Comment: How? (By the way, is Jquery code)

Comment: This is like the movie Inception.

Comment: @PepeJuan best thing would be when you can add the code into a public function. Then when the Ajax-Content is loaded (and added to the dome) call this function.

Comment: make sure all your ajax calls are inside document ready functions. when performing the second ajax call the script must be in the document body for it to be executed.